# Entity Framework 5 Navigation Property Insert Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two classes that are bound to each other with many to many relationships.

```
public class A{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> bList { get; set; }
}

public class B{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A> aList { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is I create a new object of A, initialize bList, add 3000 of objects into bList  and call Context.SaveChanges(). However, It is really slow operation , took 50 seconds or so, even each object in bList is already in database. How can I improve this insert? I have look through my sql profiler and what I see is EF calls insert statement for every A_ID and B_ID pair.

Just to note that I don't create context everytime I create once with using statement do all operations init. In addition to this, I tried to disable LazyLoading and AutoDetect = false but it didn't work either.

Best regards,

Kemal

Comment: If you have an N-to-M relationship EF will create an extra table (AB)  to save the connections. So even if the B-objects already exist, it still needs to create 3000 AB-records.

Comment: I know, the table AB already exists. Would you prefer any bulk insert pattern for this case?